# Problems with git commands in a bash script on runs following the first

Tags: bash, git

I'm strugling with a script to backup config files from root folder that copies the file inside a folder in myuser directory, reproducing the original path structure, adds the file to a git repo and commits changes. The script take the path of config file to be backed up as argument:

```
BU.sh /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Apparently the first run of program work correctly on a freshly cloned repo with only README.md, but, in the following runs, the git commands seems to have no effects.

The script is this(with some debug info added):

```
#! /bin/bash
#
set -x -e -u
export GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/config-BU/.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/
        #echo "file NOT in USER DIR, is NOT symlink";
        ls -l config-BU
        mkdir -p /home/myuser/config-BU/"${1%/*}";
        ls -l config-BU
        sudo install -o myuser -g myuser -m 660 "$1" "/home/myuser/config-BU$(realpath $1)";
        ls -l config-BU
        sudo -k;
        git status
        git ls-files
        git add "/home/myuser/config-BU$(realpath $1)";
        git ls-files
        git commit -am "adding file inside BU autom: file NOT in user folder" -m "$(realpath $1)";
        git log
```

Two runs of the command result in:

```
MYPROMPT>:~$ ./cp2bu2_badpart.sh /var/log/faillog
+ export GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/config-BU/.git
+ GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/config-BU/.git
+ export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/
+ GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/
+ ls -l config-BU
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 27 Jul  7 19:40 README.md
+ mkdir -p /home/myuser/config-BU//var/log
+ ls -l config-BU
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   27 Jul  7 19:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  7 22:25 var
++ realpath /var/log/faillog
+ sudo install -o myuser -g myuser -m 660 /var/log/faillog /home/myuser/config-BU/var/log/faillog
[sudo] password for myuser:
+ ls -l config-BU
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   27 Jul  7 19:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  7 22:25 var
+ sudo -k
+ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
deleted:    README.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

==LIST OF FILES IN MY HOME DIR==
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
+ git ls-files
README.md
++ realpath /var/log/faillog
+ git add /home/myuser/config-BU/var/log/faillog
+ git ls-files
README.md
++ realpath /var/log/faillog
+ git commit -am 'adding file inside BU autom: file NOT in user folder' -m /var/log/faillog
[main 2487ec3] adding file inside BU autom: file NOT in user folder
 1 file changed, 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 README.md
+ git log
commit 2487ec3857d355313971f2a45ba7d318870bc219 (HEAD -> main)
Author: myuser <myemail>
Date:   Fri Jul 7 22:26:41 2023 +0200

    adding file inside BU autom: file NOT in user folder
   
    /var/log/faillog

commit 84112df2c48137f247af78497e416182f0e0c24c (origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Pippetta87 <18510788+Pippetta87@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 13 03:59:13 2022 +0200

    Create README.md

MYPROMPT>:~$ ./cp2bu2_badpart.sh /etc/X11/rgb.txt
+ export GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/config-BU/.git
+ GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/config-BU/.git
+ export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/
+ GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/
+ ls -l config-BU
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   27 Jul  7 19:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  7 22:25 var
+ mkdir -p /home/myuser/config-BU//etc/X11
+ ls -l config-BU
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   27 Jul  7 19:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  7 22:27 etc
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  7 22:25 var
++ realpath /etc/X11/rgb.txt
+ sudo install -o myuser -g myuser -m 660 /etc/X11/rgb.txt /home/myuser/config-BU/etc/X11/rgb.txt
[sudo] password for myuser:
+ ls -l config-BU
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   27 Jul  7 19:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  7 22:27 etc
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  7 22:25 var
+ sudo -k
+ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

==LIST OF FILES IN MY HOME DIR==

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
+ git ls-files
++ realpath /etc/X11/rgb.txt
+ git add /home/myuser/config-BU/etc/X11/rgb.txt
+ git ls-files
++ realpath /etc/X11/rgb.txt
+ git commit -am 'adding file inside BU autom: file NOT in user folder' -m /etc/X11/rgb.txt
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

==LIST OF FILES IN MY HOME DIR==

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

As you can see the second run do not add file to git repo and last git log is not executed: the git commands after `git status` seems to be ignored.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start your script with:

```
export GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/config-BU/.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/
```

Your working dir should actually be `/home/myuser/config-BU`.

That's why when you run `git status` you see:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
deleted:    README.md
```

It can't find `README.md` in your `GIT_WORK_TREE` (`/home/myuser/README.md`), so it thinks that this file was deleted.

Then when you commit your change, you see again that it deletes `README.md` from the index:

```
git commit -am 'adding file inside BU autom: file NOT in user folder' -m /var/log/faillog
[main 2487ec3] adding file inside BU autom: file NOT in user folder
 1 file changed, 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 README.md
```

Comment: I'm using user directory as GIT_WORK_TREE since in the full script I just add to git repository configuration files (without copying them inside config-BU): I need to fix that part ... may just need to git clone with GIT_WORK_TREE sets!?